# Android Timestamps to real time in Minutes and seconds

Tags: php, android, time, graph, timestamp

I have about 1000 Android generated timestamps in a text file. Now, I need to check if the difference between two consecutive timestamps is lesser than threshold value. If yes, I need to add this TIME in MINUTES to a variable continously... If not, add the time in MINUTES in another variable...

How do I convert the timestamps into actual time . ONLY using PHP !  Or is there another way to do this without converting it to time? (because timestamps are random, just adding the consecutive differences does not help )

Comment: can you rephrase your question, its abit vague, what are you trying to achieve, are the timestamps unix timestamps and whats the threshold value?

Comment: Hi, timestamps are generated by an android process .. it looks like this : 1298083876650  ... Please read it again.. as I said , these timestamps are randomly generated and there are about 1200 timestamps for 2 hours ... I need to check if all the timestamps were logged based on the threshold... say 30 min... If no timestamps is found for 30 minutes, I 'd call it Offtime and if timestamps were found, I will call in ontime... This means that if there were no timestamps for 30 minutes, Ontime would be 1.5 hours and offtime would be 30 minutes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the timestamps are regular millisecond-resolution timestamps, then it's just a matter of feeding them into PHP's date() format, divided by 1000:

e.g.:

```
$str = date('r', 1298083876650/1000); // Fri, 18 Feb 2011 20:51:16 -0600
```

Comment: Thanks.. THe output is Sat, 19 Feb 2011 02:51:16 +0000 ... Now, how do I compare minutes alone for thousands of these timestamps? I haven't studied time based fns in PHP ..

Comment: They're just total milliseconds since Jan 1/1970 - just do `($timestamp2 - $timestamp1) / 60000` to convert the difference in milliseconds to minutes. (60 seconds / minute * 1000 milliseconds/second)

Comment: I was doin that, the error was in some parsing due to an extra comma at the end .. Thanks fr the help !!

Comment: Don't forget to mark his question as right :) You do so by clicking the little green checkbox icon next to his answer.